# access to .bashrc is denied on WSL ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing WSL Ubuntu, I edited `.bashrc` using Notepad.exe from Windows 10 Pro to insert a line `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

Now after starting Ubuntu terminal, a warning message is shown:

`-bash: /home/hu/.bashrc: Permission denied`

Run `ls -la` and got results as below. the attribute of file `.bashrc` is "----------".

```
hu@P52s:~$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 hu   hu   4096 Mar 25 00:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 21 13:58 ..
-rw------- 1 hu   hu   1689 Mar 25 00:43 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 hu   hu    220 Mar 21 13:58 .bash_logout
---------- 1 hu   hu   3791 Mar 26 22:02 .bashrc
drwx------ 1 hu   hu   4096 Mar 21 17:03 .cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).
Read that blog post for further details. If you somehow did that accidentally
for first time user then it is possible to revert that mistake by adding
the appropriate file permission and file owner.

- Open WSL as root: `wsl.exe --user root --distribution Distro_Name`
- Add file permission: `chmod 644 /home/hu/.bashrc`
- Add file owner: `chown UserName:GroupName /home/hu/.bashrc`

These will add appropriate NTFS Extended Attributes. But this does not mean
every time you edit the file then run those commands. Sometimes those command
may not work due to some intricacies in NTFS.

Comment: Will the `~` get expanded to root’s home directory?

Comment: Maybe it should be changed to `/home/hu/.bashrc` instead so it edits the user’s bashrc file?

Comment: solved my trouble like a charm!